# Batch Loop Calls to Mysql not Working

Tags: mysql, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to import 169 backup files from a folder to mysql. So, I made a batch file to do that job. It goes as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: Loops through the folder
for /r backups %%i in (*.sql) do (

    :: Shows the current filename
    echo %%i

    :: Prepares a variable with the file content (query)
    set content=
    for /F "delims=" %%a in (%%i) do @set content=!content! %%a

    :: Calls MySQL giving it the query from the file
    C:\WampServer\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysql -u root -pdev123 -e "!content!"

)

EndLocal
```

The problem is that it only seems to work for the first and the last files.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, the password is only a temp one. No worries about security as it's just a local task.

Comment: Replace the `C:\WampServer` line with `echo "!content!" & pause` and make sure of what it is doing.

Comment: Ok, it seems the problem is something about this. Looks like the loop that reads the file is limiting the amount of lines read. Is there a limit of repetitions?

Comment: There is an 8KB line length limit in XP and later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line to handle long filenames with spaces and `&` etc.

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%i") do @set content=!content! %%a
```

Answer (score 0):

After all, I was doind things harder than they should be. Instead of giving mysql the query, I just gave it the path to import the file, like this:

```
@echo off

:: Loops through the folder
for /r backups %%i in (*.sql) do (

    :: Shows the current filename
    echo %%i

    :: Calls MySQL giving it the filename to import
    C:\WampServer\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysql -u root -pdev123 < %%i

)
```

Worked like a charm. Much faster than I expected.